# how to print first name, last name and birthday in python?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to print first name, last name and birthday, so how i could do it?

Here's my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime, date

pd.set_option('display.max_rows', None)
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
pd.set_option('display.width', None)
pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', -1)
df = pd.read_csv("legislators-current.csv")
df.shape

oldest = df['birthday'].min()
print(oldest)
```

Output should be like this:

| last_name | first_name | birthday |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Cawthorn | David | 1995-08-01 |

Comment: Your question is unclear and non-reproducible, please provide your input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First add `parse_dates` to [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) for datetimes:

```
df = pd.read_csv("legislators-current.csv", parse_dates=['birthday'])
```

Then if need filter by minimal `birthday` and columns in list use [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
df.loc[df['birthday'].eq(df['birthday'].min()), ['last_name','first_name','birthday']]
```

For all columns use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df[df['birthday'].eq(df['birthday'].min())]
```

Answer (score 0):

You should output the dataframe, you can try to order it by `birthday` and then print the first row with `.head(1)`. This is an alternative to jezrael's useful answer:

```
df.sort_values('birthday').head(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my code. There are many like it, but this one is mine :)

###### It is not a bad idea to set "birthday" Dtype as "datetime" so python can compare the values. The code will work without that, but sometimes we could get unwanted results.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "last_name":["Cawthron","Doe"],
    "first_name":["David","John"],
    "birthday":["1995-08-01","1994-07-13"]
})
df['birthday'] = pd.to_datetime(df['birthday'],format='%Y/%m/%d')

df
```

|  | last_name | first_name | birthday |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Cawthron | David | 1995-08-01 |
| 1 | Doe | John | 1994-07-13 |

Below we select the row of DataFrame for which birthday minimum is true.

```
oldest = df[df["birthday"] == df['birthday'].min()]
oldest
```

|  | last_name | first_name | birthday |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Doe | John | 1994-07-13 |

Hope this helped.